# Unable to create correct route in mvc5 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I am trying to create route for one of the action of my web application but i am unable to do so. This is the current url : 
   http://localhost:8093/Profile/Get?Name=John
Which i want to change to 
  http://localhost:8093/Profile/John

In my RouteConfig i have tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Profile",
             url: "Profile/Get/{Name}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Get", Name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Profile",
             url: "Profile/{Name}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Get", Name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But nothing Works. Need a bit of guidance as to what i am doing wrong.

This is the RegisterRoutes Method

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Unauthorized",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Unauthorized", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "PageNotFound",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "PageNotFound", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "InternalServerError",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "InternalServerError", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }

routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Profile",
         url: "Profile/{Name}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Get", Name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Could you please show us your complete RouteConfig.cs file?

Comment: @Priyank : Added the Register Route method to the above code for you reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one and change your custom controller name and action name:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

you dont need to use query string in url setting.

Comment: That i have already done as mentioned in the question. Only diff is that instead of default my route name is different

Comment: you use {Name} in your url setting, but {Name} use as query string in your address, query string doesnt need exist in your url setting

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `default` route, it should always be at the last. The `RouteConfig.cs` file is read from top to bottom and will go to the first route it finds matching to the URL. Kindly change your `RouteConfig.cs` to the one given below.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Profile",
         url: "Profile/{Name}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Get", Name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Unauthorized",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Unauthorized", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "PageNotFound",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "PageNotFound", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "InternalServerError",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "InternalServerError", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

Comment: It is not working. What's happening is that as soon as i place default at the bottom of the file, i get error resource not found for my url localhost://8093 so i have to type whole 'Home/Index'. Also most of the methods in Profile controller stop working. I want default to be the route for them instead of profile and profile path for just 1 method in profile controller.